# Draw an image on top of another in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a question which I have been able to solve for a while now and had no luck. 
I have a image (hardware switch) which I have disabled (off) to begin with. The image is light. Then when the switch is enabled (on), I need to draw the enabled switch image on top of it. Does anyone have any code that would draw an image on top of another (same dimensions). My code always draws the enabled after the disabled so both show.

Comment: What do you mean by "draw an image on top of another"? Should both images be visible? Or, should only one image be visible?

Comment: Only one image at a time. So when the switch is disabled the disabled image should be visible and when the switch is enabled, the enabled image should be drawn on top of it (and vice-versa)

Comment: What is "switch"? Should images be toggled by user action?, for example, a click? Can you include `html`, `css`, `javascript` that you have tried at Question?

Comment: Do you "draw an image" in the sense of drawing on a `<canvas>` element, or just position an `<img>` over the top of some other `<img>`? Or could your problem be solved by dynamically modifying the `src` property of a single `<img>` element? Please [edit] your question to show the relevant HTML and JS.

Answer (score 0):

It can be overlapped using

> z-index

. If you want to keep the image in the background use

> z-index:-1 and the foreground image z-index:1

P.S.: In the sample used jquery as you had a jquery tag to it. and the sample is only for switching on and not a toggle.

Sample Code:

```
$(document).on('click', '#switch', function() {
  $('.off').css("z-index", -1);
  $('.on').css("z-index", 1);
})
```

[Sample Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t0twsm8o/)